# installing and using advanced nova media library in other admin panels

Tags: laravel-5.8

i am working on a project which requires file manager and was hoping to use the advanced nova media library. the problem is that when i try to install the package via composer it throws error saying it requires laravel/nova. can this package be used in projects besides laravel Nova?. if so can anybody help me on this?

Comment: This  is specifically a plugin for nova therefore does require it and wont work on its own.

Comment: oh too bad, thank you for your answer tho.